# Why mongoose populate doesn't work when populating an array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 schemas:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PinSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  image: String,
  latitude: Number,
  longitude: Number,
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  comments: [
    {
      text: String,
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        author: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: "User"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Pin", PinSchema);
```

and

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  picture: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

As you can see `author` field in Pin is the same as the `_id` in User schema.

I then try to populate the comments `author` field in the Pin schema like this:

```
const pinUpdated = await Pin.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: pinId },
        { $push: { comments: "some comment" } },
        { new: true }
      ).populate("author")
       .populate("comments.author");
```

however the result object has `author` field set to `null` so population doesn't work.

I'm not against doing this with native mongo syntax using `$lookup` but in my case it's not just looking up an array it's looking up a field of an objects array:

```
db.pins.aggregate([
    {
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "users",
       localField: "comments._id", // this won't work
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "authorOutput"
     }
}    
])
```

what am I missing in `populate()`?

Comment: Can you try `populate("author").populate("comments.author").exec();` which actually returns a full promise.

Comment: @ambianBeing `exec` didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `author` field in the `comments` array is nested inside the `createdAt` object, which is likely unintentional. Changing `PinSchema` to the following (closing curly brace before author) should fix it:

```
const PinSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  comments: [
    {
      text: String,
      createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
      },
      author: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: "User"
      }
    }
  ]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Comment: indeed that was the problem thanks! can you please add comma after `createdAt` object?

Comment: Done! Glad it helped.